# Giving NameError in sikuliX IDE 1.1.1 using Python on Win 32-bit OS

Tags: python, excel, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I would like to automate **excel** by *SikuliX* with below script but I don't know why it is giving following error in my script on 8th line.

[image]
and below is my excel file on which I want this automation.

[image]
Please guide, your contribution will have been worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use popup (lowercase). You can find the documentation [here](http://doc.sikuli.org/globals.html#popup)